# Беззнаковый string

Tags: c++, строки, char

В С++ можно создать беззнаковый тип char, который может хранить числа от 0 до 255. Я хочу использовать string похожим образом, т.е чтобы символы в нем хранились не как char, а как unsigned char. Как мне это сделать? Т.е. каким образом я могу указать string хранить беззнаковые символы?

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    unsigned char c = 240;
    string s;
    s = c;
    cout << int (c);// выводит 240
    cout << endl;
    cout << int(s[0]);//выводит -16, а я хочу 240
}
```

Comment: `cout << static_cast< unsigned int >(static_cast< unsigned char >(s[0]));`

Comment: Зачем вам это нужно? Смахивает на [проблему XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy).

Comment: Решал задачу. Используя unsigned char  ее легко решил, но используя string - увы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте что-то вроде

```
using ustring = basic_string<unsigned char>;

ustring u;
unsigned char c = 240;
u = c;
cout << int (c);// выводит 240
cout << endl;
cout << int(u[0]);//выводит -16, а я хочу 240
```

Только при этом будет сложно в смысле работы с обычными строками - те же конструкторы будут требовать `unsigned char *`, не будет оператора вывода `<<` и так далее...